# Power BI: How to count the numbers of event per time interval in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, data-science, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have a column that is numbered from 0 to 1440 with intervals of 5 so like 0, 5, 10... 1440.
I have two other columns in another table that are the start and end time of different user activity in minutes. So for example 1AM would be 60 and 6PM would be 1080.

My goal is to find how many user activity there were for every interval and organize these data to show which time periods were most active and least active.

For example:

Table A
|  Times   |
| -------- |
| 0        |
| 5        |
| 10       |
| 15       |

Table B
| Start time | End time |
| ---------- | -------- |
| 0          | 15       |
| 5          | 20       |
| 15         | 40       |

Result Table A
|  Times   | Activity |
| -------- | -------- |
| 0        | 1        |
| 5        | 2        |
| 10       | 2        |
| 15       | 3        |

Also another thing, if it starts at 10:30PM and ends at 12:30AM, that would be 1350 and 50, not sure how to say that 11PM (1380) is in between that time.

I've tried using Power Query Editor, and DAX and read countless threads and videos but still can't figure it out. The times were initally in DD:HH:MM:SS format but I converted them into minutes for easier calculations and tried to turn all the lists into a single table and compare to the table but it also didn't work for some reason. Tried doing contain with the lists or ><= operators with the start and end times but it keep giving me errors.